# Why does Xcode autocomplete always put my custom code snippets above actual completions?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, xcode9, xcode9.3

I am using some personal Xcode snippets for shortcuts for like dispatching on main queue, or a `@synchronized` code. They have never interfered with Xcode's autocomplete function with regular methods.

Some time ago I've formatted my Mac, installed Xcode, and re-created the shortcuts the same way I did before:

[image]

Ever since, my shortcuts are *always* before anything else when autocompleting methods containing spaces, as seen below:

[image]

The completion for methods should obviously come before my custom snippets.

It also occurs before anything else on property completions either:

[image]

They should get listed and highlighted as I type `d` or `dm`, or `s`, `sy` and so on, just like the default snippets. They shouldn't be at top of everything.

Why would have it changed after the format, and how do I correct this (mis)behavior?

(I am currently on Xcode 9.3 but the problem used to occur before 9.3 too)

**UPDATE:** The issue still persists on Xcode 9.4.

**UPDATE 2:** The issue still persists on Xcode 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a new update Xcode 9.4, try with the update because I had the same problem, my solution was delete Xcode and reinstall the latest version, but I think only you need to clear the configuration to return like a first launch.

In the release note for Xcode 9.3 says:

- Text in the Code Snippets library filter bar now includes code completion shortcuts. (8147546)
- User-defined code snippets now appear at the top of the library, rather than the bottom. (8901028)

You can read full changes here [Xcode Releases Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hmmm, so the "bug" is actually a feature. Just wondering if there's any (non hacky) way to revert this behavior to use snippets/autocomplete as before.